# A theoretical question using TCP sliding window: how is a mismatching window size handled?

Tags: tcp, sliding-window

I know this probably doesn't happen in real life at all, but I am curious. I was studying for an exam and came across a theoretical question while doing some sliding window problems as I wrote one down incorrectly; what happens if the RWS (receiving window size) and SWS (sending window size) are somehow mismatched? As an example, let's say I'm sending 10 packets of information, with a timeout of 1 RTT, but the SWS is 4 but the RWS is 3. For this purpose, let's say that the RX side is not able to send an ACK for packet 1 before packet 4 arrives so the window is not "slid" in time.

My idea was that the extra 4th packet is just discarded and never ACK'ed, so it would time out on the TX end and resend packet 4 after 1 RTT, and continue this process for 5,6,7,8 with 8 being the one discarded and having the same process done. Would this be a correct assumption? Or is there something to this that I'm maybe not understanding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The situation you descriebe is not legal. TCP does not permit yoiu to send more data than the advertised receive window. There is therefore no 'correct' behaviour defined for it.

Comment: Got it. Thank you user! I'd accept your answer if you want to post it below.